# Where the regex is going wrong

Tags: regex, perl

I have a query which result in the following data

Query :

```
db2 "select RTRIM(substr(A.TBSP_NAME,1,30)),A.TBSP_FREE_PAGES as FREE,B.CONTAINER_NAME as CON_PATH from SYSIBMADM.TBSP_UTILIZATION A ,SYSIBMADM.CONTAINER_UTILIZATION B where A.TBSP_ID=B.TBSP_ID and A.TBSP_AUTO_RESIZE_ENABLED=0 with UR"
```

Result :

```
1                              FREE                 CON_PATH                                                                                                                                                                                             
 ------------------------------ -------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 USERSPACE1                                    14736 /adrst/bdts/userspc_container                                                                                                                                                                        
 USERSPACE1                                    14736 /adrst/bdts/userspc_container1                                                                                                                                                                       
 MASTER                                         3472 /adrst/bdts/master_container                                                                                                                                                                         
 TRANS_DATA                                     1200 /adrst/bdts/trans_data_container                                                                                                                                                                     
 MASTER_INDEX                                   1840 /adrst/bdts/master_index_container                                                                                                                                                                   
 TRANSACTION_INDEX                               960 /adrst/bdts/transaction_index_container                                                                                                                                                              
 TEMP_SYS                                       2192 /adrst/bdts/temp_sys_container                                                                                                                                                                       
 AUDIT_DATA                                     3360 /adrst/bdts/audit_data_container                                                                                                                                                                     
 TEMP_USR                                       2672 /adrst/bdts/temp_usr_container                                                                                                                                                                       
 TSASNCA                                        2840 /home/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00002/TSASNCA                                                                                                                                                    
 TSASNUOW                                       2880 /home/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00002/TSASNUOW                                                                                                                                                   
 TSASNAA                                        3712 /home/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00002/TSASNAA                                                                                                                                                    
 TSCDADDRESSMASTER                              2048 /home/db2inst1/db2inst1/NODE0000/SQL00002/CDADDRESSMASTER                                                                                                                                            

   13 record(s) selected.
```

Now im writing a script which takes the column 2 and compares , if < 1000 then we mention col1 and col2 in print

So the script i have written is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


`db2 "connect to awdrt"`;
my @tbsp= grep /([a-zA-Z_]*)\s*([0-9]*)\s*([a-zA-Z_]*)/,`db2 "select RTRIM(substr(A.TBSP_NAME,1,30)),A.TBSP_FREE_PAGES as FREE,B.CONTAINER_NAME as CON_PATH from SYSIBMADM.TBSP_UTILIZATION A ,SYSIBMADM.CONTAINER_UTILIZATION B where A.TBSP_ID=B.TBSP_ID and A.TBSP_AUTO_RESIZE_ENABLED=0 with UR"`;

print "@tbsp";
```

I have given the print to test I am successful in eliminating the '-----' 1'st line and the last line ...so that i can split and initialize to 3 variables and do my calculation in foreach loop , but going wrong somewhere ........Help is appreciated

Comment: Where are you checking `< 1000`?

Comment: Why you don't use [DBD::DB2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::DB2)?

Comment: Your regex matches, empty lines due to all those stars. It also matches every possible string in existence.

Comment: i will check for < 1000 once i eliminate successfully the top and bottom lines , just want to check if grep is giving desired O/p so .......

Comment: yah I have already written the script with DBD::DB2 and its working fine , just want to try out without it , actually trying to get some grip on regex so ..........

Comment: can somebody give me or guide me the right regex..........?

Comment: If you already have it working with `DBI`, using regex is masochism.

Comment: @mvp Thanks for mentioning me masochism, no regrets  , I'm learning in Perl and I have already told I'm trying different ways of possibilities in Perl ......now the answer please..........

Answer (score 0):

```
# loop over the query output
for (`db2 "select ...`) {
  if (my ($c0, $c1, $c2) = /(\w+)\s*(\d+)\s*([\w\/]+)/) {
    print "$c0,$c1,$c2\n";
  }   
}
```

Comment: I am not that comfortable as shell as i started working with it a week back or so , so can't i get a regex which helps in grepping a name followed by a digits followed by a string ......?

Comment: see the 1st column need not start with a digit "1" as I have shown , it may have a name if i alias it , does this regex work at the point ....?

Comment: may be i can use split with some regex to initialize it 3 variables , see i'm just guessing myself ....suggestions are appreciated

Comment: I have grepped with the regex "**/\//**" , so I can get the data what i wanted actually so how do I initialize it variables using foreach or anything else...............?

Comment: @mViswa, OK this should do it

Comment: **#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


`db2 "connect to awdrt"`;
my @tbsp= grep /\//,`db2 "select RTRIM(substr(A.TBSP_NAME,1,30)),A.TBSP_FREE_PAGES as FREE,B.CONTAINER_NAME as CON_PATH from SYSIBMADM.TBSP_UTILIZATION A ,SYSIBMADM.CONTAINER_UTILIZATION B where A.TBSP_ID=B.TBSP_ID and A.TBSP_AUTO_RESIZE_ENABLED=0 with UR"`;

print "@tbsp";**

Comment: the problem with grep is, you will flatten the table. You will end up with a single row/column.

Comment: yah that is what I am also thinking , how do i split and with what source of a delimiter i split it ......?

Comment: Wow it works ..........thanks man , let me try of a few other thing and come back

Comment: this is also working ....... **#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


`db2 "connect to awdrt"`;
my @tbsp= grep /\//,`db2 "select RTRIM(substr(A.TBSP_NAME,1,30)),A.TBSP_FREE_PAGES as FREE,B.CONTAINER_NAME as CON_PATH from SYSIBMADM.TBSP_UTILIZATION A ,SYSIBMADM.CONTAINER_UTILIZATION B where A.TBSP_ID=B.TBSP_ID and A.TBSP_AUTO_RESIZE_ENABLED=0 with UR"`;

foreach (@tbsp){
chomp;
my ($col1,$col2,$col3)=split /\s+/,$_,3;
print "$col1,$col2,$col3\n";
}**

Answer (score 0):

You can include the filtering of lines having FREE > 1000 in a single grep, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @lines = <DATA>;

my @filtered = grep {/(\S+) # non-space characters
              \s+ # one or more spaces
              (\d+) # numeric characters
              \s+ # one or more spaces
              (\S+) # non-space characters
             /x,
               $2 > 1000 # filter by FREE > 1000
             } @lines;
```

In other words, first filter the data lines with a regex, then return only lines having FREE > 1000.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for the question i asked .......

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $good = "\[\033[32mOK\033[0m\]";
my $bad = "\[\033[31m!!\033[0m\]";


`db2 "connect to awdrt"`;
my @tbsp= grep /\//,`db2 "select RTRIM(substr(A.TBSP_NAME,1,30)),A.TBSP_FREE_PAGES as FREE,B.CONTAINER_NAME as CON_PATH from SYSIBMADM.TBSP_UTILIZATION A ,SYSIBMADM.CONTAINER_UTILIZATION B where A.TBSP_ID=B.TBSP_ID and A.TBSP_AUTO_RESIZE_ENABLED=0 with UR"`;

foreach (@tbsp){
chomp;
s/^\s*//;
s/\s*$//;
my ($col1,$col2,$col3)=split /\s+/,$_,3;
if ($col2 <= 2000){
print "$bad $col1 has $col2 pages with container $col3\n";
#print "alter tablespace $col1 extend (file \'$col3\' 1000)\n";
}
}
```

And its working fine ..............**Thanks all**